# Why are we [hosting] this tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, synonym-request, clean-up

From the [hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hosting) description:

> Hosting refers to the commercial service offered by companies that let you run websites using their servers. Questions about server technology are probably best asked at serverfault.com and more general questions at webmasters.stackexchange.com.

"Probably?" Questions about server technology **are** best asked at serverfault.com, no "probably" about it.

Are there any valid use cases for this?

Also, why do we have both a [hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hosting) and a [web-hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-hosting) tag? Can we at least make these synonyms and clean them up, if not burning them outright?

The requirements for burnination:

**"Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?"** Yeah... I suppose.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?** No, questions about web hosting belong on Server Fault or Webmasters.SE.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?** Yes, it identifies it as an off-topic or mistagged question ;)

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?** I suppose.

The biggest argument for outright burnination here is that web hosting questions are off-topic. All of the on-topic questions should be able to be retagged, and the ones that can't be retagged probably need to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @Adriaan afaik, the only difference is on what port are you listening and what you return. Hosting anything, is exactly the same on all systems.

Comment: ooh yeah this is tag I'm ready to put in effort to burn, it surely generates off-topic questions, but wow it is massive so it needs a lot of support.

Comment: Is it possible that there are problems peculiar to programming in a hosted environment, such as some specific thing about PHP or similar? I'm skeptical there is, but no harm in thinking about it.