# Need to [ir]radiate this tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[ir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ir)

Ran across this today and it's loaded with bad questions. The excerpt itself condemns it

> **This tag is ambiguous, do not use**. For questions about LLVM intermediate representation, use [llvm-ir]. For questions about infrared technology and protocols, use [infrared]. For questions about information retrieval, use [information-retrieval].

The most common misuse is with [infrared], with LLVM coming a distant second (the on-topic ones need a retag to [llvm-ir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/llvm-ir)). But there's a lot of them that just need removal for being off-topic.

Comment: I agree - talk about a useless tag.

Comment: Burn it. Blacklist it. Note: These are separate requests. If you desire for it to be blacklisted, you should add the [meta-tag:blacklist-request] tag.

Comment: If we [ir]radiate it, would we be able to [convert] it to something more useful (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355395/lets-convert-this-to-a-better-tag), or would we just stop [hosting] it on this [website] altogether? (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355124/why-are-we-hosting-this-tag)? Or does it depend on which [mode] we use? Are there [rules] that we need to be in [compliance] with?

Comment: it is so [ir]ritating and [ir]rational   .... lol  .... could not resist .... i hope i did not [ir]k anyone

Comment: @Makyen: blacklisting is only appropriate for tags that refuse to die (repeatedly come back from burnination).

Comment: [ir] irá en otra parte!

Comment: @MartijnPieters, OK. However, with 3 meanings already listed in its tag excerpt, I consider it *highly* likely that the tag will be recreated, multiple times. I'm certainly willing to comply with policy. However, for this tag, IMO waiting for [tag:ir]'s inevitable multiple resurrections is a planned waste of unneeded future-effort to re-clean the tag once it's gone through the process of being forgotten, resurrected and noticed again a couple/few years from now. While *any* blacklisting should be on a case-by-case basis, IMO doing this one now will save inevitable effort later.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I may have to agree with Makyen here, he does bring up a good point. The same thing happened with [convert], apparently - it was burned in 2012 and came back and now has 739 questions last I checked, so if we end up [burning it again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355395/lets-convert-this-to-a-better-tag) the fact that it wasn't blacklisted last time will end up causing us a lot of extra work. Either way, would there be some kind of harm in blacklisting it (other than needing to bug a CM to do it)?

Comment: @EJoshuaS: if and when it comes back and it really becomes a problem, **then** is the time to blacklist, and not before.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, We burn tags with uses obvious to people unfamiliar with the tag system and why some tags are bad. Burning such tags is quite a bit of effort. Because the tag's use is obvious to the uninitiated, and those people are putting most tags in questions, such tags *will* be used. Thus, we either monitor and correct, or prevent the use. Monitoring and correcting costs time/effort either continuously or in batches (burniation). IMO, the rules should be a bit more flexible to permit, *in some cases*, choosing to blacklist a tag which is very likely to be a repeat problem.

Comment: @Makyen: there is a minimum rep involved with creating a tag, which creates a barrier. Until the tag is actually recreated and produces enough of an issue, will we actually *know* it is a troublesome tag. The vast majority of burninated tags do not come back, or not in great enough numbers to be an issue.

Comment: @Makyen: in this case we are talking about a few hundred posts tagged in 8 years. That is a pittance, this is not a troublesome tag.

Comment: Questions about infra-red light/diodes aren't even on-topic, they should be asked at https://electronics.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @Lundin did I miss something, or is this was supposed to be a reply to a deleted comment? How about using infrared as communication mode just like Bluetooth?

Comment: @AndrewT. Infrared is a physical phenomenon - a color. IR diodes are electronic components. None which has the slightest to do with programming. Bluetooth however, does not just involve "radio" but a very specific radio frequency, with standardized protocols specified all the way up through the OSI model, including the application level. So it is a poor comparison. Rather, equivalent tags to infrared would be "radio", "wires", "magnetic fields" etc. All of it useless, off-topic tags.

Comment: @Lundin Feel free to make a separate burninate for [infrared]. I tend to view it like [chemistry], which makes it a harder burninate

Comment: Remember that it's easier to disambiguate a tag if it's blacklisted. Through, considering that it had only 1 new question in the last 30 days, I think a single user can fix this without fighting the tide.

Comment: There are only 104 questions at the moment with the [tag:ir] tag.  They can be processed by anyone with the privileges to edit questions without troubling the review queues to deal with the issue without further ado.  There's clearly a consensus that the tag is not useful.  Once all the questions are retagged (or untagged) with [ir], the tag will die.  It'll likely stay dead.